# Multi textures and multi lights in OpenGL 3.3

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have a project of castle and i send one light and one material to shaders. I want to add one more light and texture, but i don't know how to do it in shaders.
This is my fragment shader:

```
#version 130        

out vec4 pixelColor; 

in vec4 l;
in vec4 n;
in vec4 v;

uniform sampler2D textureMap0, textureMap1;
in vec2 iTexCoord;
in vec2 iTexCoord2;
uniform vec4 dragi1; 
uniform vec4 dragi2;
uniform vec4 dragi3;
uniform float polysk;

uniform vec4 Light0ambient;
uniform vec4 Light0diffuse;
uniform vec4 Light0specular;
uniform vec4 Light0position;

uniform vec4 Material0emission;
uniform vec4 Material0ambient;
uniform vec4 Material0diffuse;
uniform vec4 Material0specular;
uniform float Material0shininess;

void main(void) {

  vec4 ml=normalize(l);
  vec4 mn=normalize(n);
  vec4 mv=normalize(v);
  vec4 mr=reflect(-ml,mn);

  float nl=max(dot(ml,mn),0);
  float rv=pow(max(dot(mr,mv),0),Material0shininess);

  pixelColor=Light0ambient*Material0ambient+Light0diffuse*Md*vec4(nl,nl,nl,1)+Light0specular*Material0specular*vec4(rv,rv,rv,0);
}
```

And this is my vertex shader:

```
#version 130

uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;

in vec4 vertex;             
in vec4 normal;            
in vec2 texCoord;           

out vec4 l;                 
out vec4 n;                 
out vec4 v;                 

out vec2 iTexCoord;
out vec2 iTexCoord2;

uniform vec4 Light0position;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position=P*V*M*vertex;

    l=normalize(V*(Light0position-M*vertex)); 
    n=normalize(V*M*normal); 
    v=normalize(vec4(0,0,0,1)-V*M*vertex);

    iTexCoord = texCoord;
    iTexCoord2 = (n.xy + 1)/2;
}
```

It is simple to do?
And one more question, how to create a spotlight? Can i do this in simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use multiple lights in your shaders you generally store all your light and material data in arrays and process each of those in one large for-loop with or without GLSL functions.

For example, you could create a `light` and a `material` struct and create a uniform array of those structs like this:

```
struct Light {
    vec4 position;    
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
};

struct Material {
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    vec4 emission;
    float shininess;
}; 

uniform Light lights[4]; // Use 4 lights
uniform Material materials[2]; // Use 2 materials
```

Then the structure of your fragment shader could look something like this:

```
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    // define an output color value
    vec3 output;
    // calculate lighting value per light source
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        outout += someFunctionToCalculateLight(lights[i], materials[0]);
    color = vec4(output, 1.0);
}
```

In this case a function was created to calculate the resulting lighting color **per** light source and added to the final `output` color. This is generally how you work with multiple lights. Note that this is a very basic example.

Also, if you want to know how to create a spotlight, you're better off following tutorials on that subject of which there are plenty to be found online instead of asking that around here.

A few tutorials:

- http://www.mbsoftworks.sk/index.php?page=tutorials&series=1&tutorial=20
- http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/spotlights/
- http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Lighting/Light-casters

Comment: In vertex shaders can i do a loop too? And there will be l+=(V*(Light[0].position-M*vertex)); ?

Comment: Yeah, loops are a valid construct in GLSL so you can do loops in all shaders.

Comment: But calculations will be correct? I do  l+=(V*(Light[0].position-M*vertex)) and  l=(V*(Light[0].position-M*vertex)+V*(Light[1].position-M*vertex)) and it was incorrect.

Comment: I gave an example of how to work with multiple lights. It's then up to you to see if you can use/learn from this and investigate further. If it's not working it could have multiple causes. did you specify the uniforms for `lights[0]` and `lights[1]`? (query their location with `lights[0].position` as their name),